# how to save images to sqlite3 database?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have an array of UIImages, how to I save them in sqlite3 database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Veer it is upto you you that how you want to save them to the `Sqlite database` as Parth told you before you have two options have a look on them below

1. Saving images in the database as BLOB datatype.
2. Saving images name in the database as String datatype.

Now you have both the options with you........and as you are asking about that you have array of `UIImages`,and you want to save them in sqlite3 database then i suggest you to choose second one and save the `images name by separation of (,)` in same field and fetch them
accordingly.

Hope you got my point....Good Luck!

Comment: I will use image name, it is better :-)

Comment: /Sudhanshu: Being an old member of Stackoverflow you are expected to know the following: You are **NOT** suppose to copy someone's answer and add a link for tutorial. Only if your answer is different from others you should post your answer. If you feel that your answer matches existing answer then you should upvote that answer rather than posting your own answer. If you want to add something to existing answer you can edit the answer or post a comment below the answer Anyways. :\

Answer (score 2):

For saving images into Sqlite database, there are two options:

**FIRST OPTION**

You can put your images in Resources folder or may be app's Documents Directory and just save the image names as TEXT datatype in Sqlite.

**SECOND OPTION**

You can convert your images to NSData format and save it as BLOB datatype in Sqlite.

As such, First option is more feasible, if number of images is more.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: but what be structure of table, like create table hello (id, name varchar(100), image -what be datatype-)?

Comment: @Veer: if you are going with first option then datatype needs to be varchar or TEXT but if you going for second option then you need to use BLOB datatype in Sqlite. Now is it clear in terms of datatype to be used?